Regex htaccess: find a string where the same substring repeats twice
Summary: I want to create an htaccess redirect that redirects release notes links to the current version - but the link to the current version itself hits thesame filter, which can result in an endless loop, so I want to catch this special case... and can't.
So, I have release notes per version, with URLs like this:
https://docs.example.com/product/1.12/product-release-notes-1-12.html
https://docs.example.com/product/1.13/product-release-notes-1-13.html
What I want is to use htaccess to redirect links from a wrong version to the right one, so that https://docs.example.com/product/1.12/product-release-notes-1-13.html becomes https://docs.example.com/product/1.12/product-release-notes-1-12.html .
The redirect itself is simple:
RewriteRule ^product/1\.([0-9]+)/product-release-notes?(.*).html$ product/1\.$1/product-release-notes-1-$1.html [L,R=302]

However, it also hits the correct link, resulting in an endless loop.
I can fix it by adding a "stop processing" line per version before this line, such as:
RewriteRule ^product/1\.12/product-release-notes-1-12.html$ product/1\.$1/product-release-notes-1-12.html - [L]

However, that does require adding a new line for every new version. To avoid this, Id want a regex in this line that would catch https://docs.example.com/product/1.12/product-release-notes-1-12.html and https://docs.example.com/product/1.13/product-release-notes-1-13.html but not catch https://docs.example.com/product/1.13/product-release-notes-1-12.html .
Is it possible to craft such a regex and if so, how? Thanks!


However, it also hits the correct link, resulting in an endless loop

You can avoid matching the correct link by using the first number (e.g. 12, 13 etc) in a capture group and use the back-reference of the same in the same pattern inside a negative lookahead to avoid matching the same number again in the link.
Consider following the redirect rule:
RewriteRule ^(product/1\.(\d+)/product-release-notes-1-)(?!\2\.)\d+(\.html)$ /$1$2$3 [NC,L,R=302]

Details:

We are capturing the number after 1. in the 2nd capture group i.e. (\d+)
Then in the same pattern after matching 1- we are using a negative lookahead assertion (?!\2\.) that makes regex to avoid the matches when we have the same number followed by a dot ahead of the current position.

